# is it possible to edit matplotlib plot interactively?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am not sure if this is an acceptable question in SE.
I am wondering if it is possible to edit `matplotlib` plot interactively. i.e.,

```
#  plot
plt.plot(x, y[1])
plt.plot(x, -1.0*y[2])
plt.show()
```

will open up a `tk` screen with the plot. Now, say, I want to modify the `linewidth` or enter `x/y label`. Is it possible to do that interactively (either on the screen, using mouse like `xmgrace` or from a `gnuplot` like command prompt)?

Answer (score 7):

You can do simple interactive editing with pylustrator

```
pip install pylustrator
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what (I think) you ask for is to use ipython. ipython is an interactive python environment which comes with many python distributions.

A quick example:

In a cmd, type `>>> ipython`, which will load the ipython terminal.  In ipython, type:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'r-')
fig.show()
```

Now you have a figure, at the same time as the ipython terminal is "free".  This means that you can do commands to the figure, like `ax.set_xlabel('XLABEL')`, or `ax.set_yticks([0, 5])`.  To make it show on screen, you need to redraw the canvas, which is done by calling `fig.canvas.draw()`.

Note that with ipython, you have full tab-completion with all functions to all objects!  Typing `fig.get_` and then tab gives you the full list of functions beginning with fig.get_, this is extremely helpful!

Also note that you can run python-scripts in ipython, with `run SCRIPT.py` in the ipython-cmd, and at the same time having access to all variables defined in the script.  They can then be used as above.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not generally possible to do what you want (dynamically interact with a matplotlib using the mouse). 
What you see is a rendering of your plot on a "canvas", but it does not include a graphical user interface (GUI) like you have with e.g. xmgrace, Origin *etc.*

That being said, if you wish to pursue it you have a number of possible options, including:

- Modify the matplotlib source code yourself to include a GUI
- Do something with buttons, like in YuppieNetworking's answer here:
  [Change dynamically the contents of a matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050728/change-dynamically-the-contents-of-a-matplotlib-plot)

But it is *probably* quicker and more convenient to just use some other plotting software, where someone has already designed a decent user interface for you.

Alternatively, using an iPython notebook to quickly modify your plot script works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is a navigation toolbar in qt4agg matplotlib backend which you can add easily. Not much, but at least good scaling...

[image: ![enter image description here]

Not a working code, just some fragments:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtCore, QtWidgets, is_pyqt5

self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 3))
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea,
                NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self))
```

Self is your window object derived from QtGui.QMainWindow.